# Hybrid Windows + Forms authentication in ASP.Net applications. Architectural advice sought please

Tags: asp.net, authentication, owin, wif, katana

I would like to achieve a hybrid Windows & Forms authentication for our ASP.NET web applications. I’ve seen details of several ways to do this, some on Stackoverflow, from simple re-directs to an OWIN solution which looks pretty fearsome and I honestly can’t follow what’s going on! I could really use some architecture advice please!

Currently, we have several web applications (all under one root domain) all using forms authentication. Users are re-directed to a single authentication application which verifies their credentials and checks that they have been granted access to the application they want to use. The web server is public facing, being hosted in a DMZ in an external data centre.

I would like users who are logged on to our corporate AD to be able to access these applications without having to go through forms authentication. Whereas non-corporate users such as customers, or corporate users who are not logged on to the AD (e.g. employee using a computer at a customer’s premises) are sent to a form for authentication.

Reviewing what I have read about so far:

- **Simple redirect.**

Approaches such as this - https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms972958.aspx and http://mvolo.com/iis-70-twolevel-authentication-with-forms-authentication-and-windows-authentication/ - still use forms authentication. But the logon URL target is an aspx page which is secured using Windows authentication. Domain authenticated users are able to access this page, so the Windows username can be lifted and used to create a normal forms ticket. Non-domain users will get a 401 permission denied error with IIS being configured to redirect on such errors to the normal authentication form.

This seems like a simple approach but I guess (a) it won’t work for me because the web server is in a DMZ which does not have access to our AD and (b) most references to this technique seem quite old, so I guess it’s an outdated approach.

- **Windows Identity Foundation.**

I quite like this approach. I’ve been through some material on Pluralsight, but our exact requirement is not covered. We do have AD FS 2.0 (soon to be updated to 3.0 I understand). Would it be possible to have domain users directed to AD FS, acting as a STS, to obtain a token, but non-domain users directed to a simple STS in the DMZ for username/password authentication? From the diagrams I’ve seen it appears that WIF can trust more than one STS, but can a user be automatically directed to a particular STS depending on, for example, IP address or another way to discriminate between internal/external access?

Also, I’ve seen quite a few Powerpoints around this topic, but could someone point me in the direction of some concrete examples, as I don’t seem to be able to find any.

- **OWIN/Katana.**

This would seem to be the favoured way now, with new ASP.NET projects getting this added from the start. Again, I watched some Pluralsight videos. I followed the idea of a request pipeline and middleware (I’ve used BizTalk a lot so the concept is familiar). But I lost the plot when it got to authentication middleware. I’ll have to re-visit the material. I did find this code which says it does what I want - https://github.com/MohammadYounes/MVC5-MixedAuth/tree/WindowsFirst - but to be honest it was beyond my understanding.

Could someone please let me know whether Katana could be used to achieve what I want and whether there is a simpler method than used in this sample code?

So, overall, I guess I could use some advice about which of these approaches I should use. Or is there a better way? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is to install an ADFS Proxy / WAP.

Then using split DNS, external users redirect to the proxy (FBA) and internal users redirect to the internal ADFS (IWA).

The problem with WIF / OWIN etc., is that they get you to ADFS but they don't determine how ADFS authenticates.

Comment: Hi. Many thanks for the help. I'll follow up this suggestion. Doug.